# Having trouble using reverse()

Tags: python, django, django-urls

It feels like this is a simple problem but I am obviously missing something.

```
url = reverse('specific', args=(var.pk,))
print(url)
```

The error message i get is:

```
Reverse for 'specific' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Here are my urls:

For myapp level

```
    urlpatterns = [
    ... some stuff ...
    url(r'^specific/(?P<var_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.specific, name='specific'),
]
```

And these are for the project level

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.index', name='index'),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls', namespace="TestData")),
```

]

Feels like I'm missing something simple but I am new at this

Comment: Please provide your `urls.py`. Also where in your code are calling `reverse`? From the error message, no urls at all are loaded at this point.

Comment: Did you try `args=var.pk`

Comment: It's called in a test, but i get the same message when i call it within another view, such as my index view

Comment: Yeah when i try args=var.pk i get this error:
_reverse_with_prefix() argument after * must be a sequence, not int

Comment: `var_id` is a named group in your `urls.py`, so why not try with `reverse('specific', kwargs={'var_id': var.pk})`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using namespace in you project urls, `namespace="TestData"`, so you also have to provide it in your urls:

```
url = reverse('TestData:specific', args=[str(var.pk)])
```